# Split string by whitespace, keeping escaped characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split a string by its whitespace, but keep any escaped whitespace characters.

Example line:

```
/etc/space\ in\ folder\ name/files  /mnt/files  none    defaults    0   0
```

I want to split that up by the whitespace (tab or spaces) yet keep the escaped whitespace characters (`\` ) as one item.

So in this case it would split it into 6 items.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can match any escaped character, *or* any character that isn't a space:

```js
const str = String.raw`/etc/space\ in\ folder\ name/files  /mnt/files  none    defaults    0   0`;
console.log(
  str.match(/(?:\\.|\S)+/g)
);
```